# Xcode build but not run on device

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I was in the process of adding a third party library (GPUImage), I actually managed to get it all in and installed on the device. Woohoo!

Then...well you know the story. It doesn't work anymore.

Now when ever I try to build to my device it will "Build successfully" then immediately go to "Finished running".

My setup:
iPhone 4
iOS 5.1.1
OS X Lion
Xcode 4.3.2

I have:

- Tried:

  1. Adding in armv6
  2. -all_load
  3. Restarting xcode
  4. Restarting device
  5. Removing device from the organizer then adding it back.
  6. Restarting computer.
  7. Cleaning project and rebuilding
  8. Removing the "Requirements" (?) from the pList (although this app is for iOS 5.0 or higher).

None of these seem to work. If anyone has had this problem PLEEEASE help! I am about to lose my sanity.

In the mean time I will try archiving and doing and OTA install and see if that works.

Thank you very much for your time,

Cory

P.S - I have already seen all the other post on here so please don't paste links to them :)

Comment: +1 for trying everying, but did you try taking the magic bean and saying the secret incantation while chopping broccoli under a full moon?

Comment: honestly one thing that caught me was *misspelling* armv6 as amrv6.  Xcode doesn't notice the misspelling.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit srry for the misspelling, happens to me in when I have a fit of rage. But in my project it IS spelled correctly.

Comment: @ThunderRabbit Ah! That was it, I took the magic bean, said the chant, chopped the broccoli, but forgot about the full moon..              >:| stupid moon.

Comment: Could you possibly have selected to build an included framework instead of your app? This is the dropdown labeled "Scheme" in the upper left part of Xcode (next to the stop button).

Comment: Is anything being logged to the console when you try to build and run about a .app bundle being missing from DerivedData? If so, quit Xcode and go to your DerivedData directory and remove all projects you've built using this framework from there. Restart Xcode and try to build and run the application on the device. A few people have hit that with Xcode 4.3.

Comment: Neither of these solutions have worked :-/ I'm still trying. There isn't anything being logged in the organizer consol either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what fixed my problem but with the new Xcode version the problem stopped. Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Problem of Project, Scheme and Target names. This all must be a same. Try rename to same name

"AppName" and "Appname" is not true. Must be "AppName" and "AppName", or "Appname" and "Appname".

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem - I have the latest XCode iOS SDK 5.1 - but my iPhone is updated with the latest iOS version 5.1.1

Not sure how to solve this as Apple havent released the new SDK. Pretty shit to be honest, as I can't test on my device.

Comment: It has actually started working on my device without updating - unsure why it wasnt working before or why it is now...